# Create branch for Jira issue in Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jira

I have connected Jira server into my Intellij Idea. When I choose some issue from list (`shift + alt + n`) Jira usually creates new branch and checklist for that. I am working on my issue but I have o lot of errors in new branch, so it will be easier to remove branch. After I deleted it I want to Jira create branch for issue again, but after choosing issue in list nothing happened. Can you tell me how to do that after deleting previous branch? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Jira creating branches, AFAIU, but IDEA on creating a new local task associated with branch/changelist.

The IDEA TAsk plugin can only create branch/changelist on a task creating, switching to the already existing task does not do that at the moment. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-140006

So you need to open a new task, or manually create a new branch/changelist with the same name it had, and check the task settings to make sure it still tracks them